# 2 Bootstrap navbars overlapping (want one fixed below the other)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have this website that has 2 navbars, but the dark navbar keeps getting covered up by the light one, i want the light one on top and the dark one below it, what is wrong with my code?

link: https://paragon.fun/punishments/bans.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because of the `positioning` you've specified. You are using `fixed` on the light navbar and `relative` on the dark one.

It depends on what you want to achieve. If the dark navbar should be positioned `fixed` below the light one you can simply add the following CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

But if the dark navbar should simply be below the light one, without any stickiness you would need to specify the `top` distance:

```
.navbar-inverse {
  top: 50px; // equal to the light navbars height
}
```

The reason why this happens is since you are using `fixed` positioning on your light navbar it will be taken out of the `documentflow`. Fixed elements will no longer affect the positioning of `relative` positioned elements like the dark navbar.

Comment: Thanks! That got my bar below it, but it's not full screen like the other bar

Edit: It's because it's like still kinda positioned up there, in a weird way lol. not sure why that is

Comment: @AZGames I've updated my answer. You also need to add `width: 100%` and `top: 50px`

Comment: Thanks so much! While I've got you do you think you could tell me why my navbar on https://paragon.fun and http://forum.paragon.fun/ are different, they both use the same code but are formatted slightly different for some reason; suppose to look like the one on https://paragon.fun

Comment: @AZGames The `CSS` is different. this file is missing on the forum: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/styles.css">`

Comment: I had another CSS file but someone messed up that website, I'm trying to fix it to show you how it was before.

Comment: the other file is estyles.css